# How to add data to a new row in the n-th column of a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am working with incomplete historical data and am using Python to select specific information from TXT files (e.g. via Regex) and write them to .csv tables.

Is it possible to write a certain item or a list of items to new rows in a particular column in an existing CSV file?

I can add individual strings or lists as consecutive new rows or columns to an existing table, but very often, I am only filling in "missing information".

It would be great to find a way to select the next row in the **"n"-th column** of a CSV table, or to **select the column by name / column heading**.

Comment: Are you using the module 'csv' or another library to read the csv?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Pandas?

It has convenient methods for [reading](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [writing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) csv-files. Working with columns, rows, and cells is quite intuitive.

It takes a little time to understand the basics of Pandas. but if you plan to work with csv and csv-like data more than once, it is worth it.

Comment: Yes, I have used it already for adding new columns to an existing file. Reading what is there per line as a new DataFrame and then re-writing it to the table. Perhaps not the most elegant way to do it. And I did not know that I had options for writing data to individual "cells" in a table, but I will probably need to check out a few more tutorials.